# MYSQL get product records from history table for two different date with only latest data if duplicate found

Tags: mysql

I have a transaction table which holds different types of products which hold two types of products
which is stored in others field (json field) tagged as product_type1 and product_type2 and some 
products can be tagged as both.

Transaction table:

```
id, hash_value, product_name,price, date , others

1, abc, product_name1, 20, 2018-10-21, {"product_type1": 1}
2, def, product_name2, 30, 2018-10-22, {"product_type2": 1}
3, ghi, product_name3, 40, 2018-10-21, {"product_type1": 1, "product_type2": 1}
```

Unique key (id, hash_value)

For the above mentioned table, we have a history table which stores the historical products 
for the above products in transaction table (schema is same like transaction table , but unique key is on id,hash_value,date)

History table

```
id, hash_value, product_name, price, date , others
1, abc, product_name1, 20, 2018-10-21, {"product_type1": 1}
2, abc, product_name1, 18, 2018-10-20, {"product_type1": 1}
3, abc, product_name1, 19, 2018-10-19, {"product_type1": 1}
4, def, product_name2, 30, 2018-10-22, {"product_type2": 1}
4, def, product_name2, 29, 2018-10-21, {"product_type2": 1}
4, def, product_name2, 40, 2018-10-20, {"product_type2": 1}
5, ghi, product_name3, 40, 2018-10-21, {"product_type1": 1, "product_type2": 1}

5, ghi, product_name3, 50, 2018-10-22, {"product_type1": 1, "product_type2": 1}
```

I would like to query records with following condition.
1. Get all records tagged as product_type1 for date 2018-10-21
2. Get all records tagged as product_type2 for date 2018-10-22
3. If tagged as both then, get records having latest date.

The query i tried.

```
SELECT *
FROM   ((SELECT *
         FROM   history_table
         WHERE  date = '2018-10-21'
                AND others ->> '$.product_type1' == 1)
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT *
         FROM   history_table
         WHERE  date = '2018-10-22'
                AND others ->> '$.product_type2' == 1))
```

but the result i get is

```
id, hash_value, product_name, price, date , others
1, abc, product_name1, 20, 2018-10-21, {"product_type1": 1}
4, def, product_name2, 30, 2018-10-22, {"product_type2": 1}
5, ghi, product_name3, 40, 2018-10-21, {"product_type1": 1, "product_type2": 1}
5, ghi, product_name3, 50, 2018-10-22, {"product_type1": 1, "product_type2": 1}
```

Result should only give record with latest date if duplicate record for id and hash_value exists

Results Expected:

```
id, hash_value, product_name, price, date , others
1, abc, product_name1, 20, 2018-10-21, {"product_type1": 1}
4, def, product_name2, 30, 2018-10-22, {"product_type2": 1}
5, ghi, product_name3, 50, 2018-10-22, {"product_type1": 1, "product_type2": 1}
```

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? Is it 8.0.2 and above ?

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) (sub-select query), identify the maximum date value for a combination of `id` and `hash_value` matching the prescribed conditions.
- Now, simply join this result-set to the `history_table` to get the rows corresponding to maximum date value only.
- Instead of using `Union All` to combine two different conditional Select results; you can directly use `OR` in the `Where` condition here. it will be significantly more efficient.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT ht.* FROM 
history_table AS ht 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT id, hash_value, MAX(date) AS max_date 
  FROM   history_table
  WHERE  (date = '2018-10-21' AND others ->> '$.product_type1' == 1) 
          OR 
         (date = '2018-10-22' AND others ->> '$.product_type2' == 1) 
  GROUP BY id, hash_value 
) AS dt ON dt.id = ht.id AND 
           dt.hash_value = ht.hash_value AND 
           dt.max_date = ht.date
```

Comment: This looks good , but in my table i have a date_time field on which i need to use max(date_time) as for a particular day i may have many records,few of my date_time values are stored as 0000-00-00 00:00:00 (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss) may be due to error in my code.max takes these datetime as max.

Comment: @rohitvernekar Max will not return 0000 if there is already another datetime value for the same date. Can you prepare a SQL fiddle or DB fiddle showcasing your error ?

Comment: Sorry there is no error in your query, The query is perfect thanks :)